# Do the eigenvectors represent the original features?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, features, principal-component-analysis

I've got a test dataset with 4 features and the PCA produces a set of 4 eigenvectors, e.g.,

```
EigenVectors: [0.7549043055910286, 0.24177972266822534, -0.6095588015369825, -0.01000612689310429]
EigenVectors: [0.0363767549959317, -0.9435613299702559, -0.3290509434298886, -0.009706951562064631]
EigenVectors: [-0.001031816289317291, 0.004364438034564146, 0.016866154627905586, -0.999847698334029]
EigenVectors: [-0.654824523403971, 0.2263084929291885, -0.7210264051508555, -0.010499173877772439]
```

Do the eigenvector values represent the features from the original dataset? E.g., is feature 1 & 2 explaining most of the variance in eigenvector 1?

Am I interpreting the results correct to say that features 1 and 2 are therefore the most important in my dataset since PC1 represents 90% of the variance?

I'm trying to map back to the original features but am unsure how to interpret the results.

Answer (score 2):

> The principal components (eigenvectors) correspond to the direction
>   (in the original n-dimensional space) with the greatest variance in
>   the data.
>
> The corresponding eigenvalue is a number that indicates how much
>   variance there is in the data along that eigenvector (or principal
>   component).

Thus, feature 2 is the most important (based on eigenvalue alone). Then feature 1. The other 2 features have little impact and theoretically could be removed as a part of your data reduction effort.

Also, it is important to point out that

> When performing PCA, it is typically a good idea to normalize the data
>   first. Because PCA seeks to identify the principal components with the
>   highest variance, if the data are not properly normalized, attributes
>   with large values and large variances (in absolute terms) will end up
>   dominating the first principal component when they should not.

IOW, if you didn't normalize your data then your PCA analysis is quite likely meaningless.

*The above quoted text is from http://www.lauradhamilton.com/introduction-to-principal-component-analysis-pca